# Thread.Sleep doesn't work and eternal cycle

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

```
public void Stop()
    {
        lock(_threadHandlerLock)
        {
            if(!stop)
            {
                stop = true;

                while(ThreadPool.Count > 0) // count = 1 and an eternal cycle
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); // here is a problem

                }

                LoggerHandler.Info(string.Format("{0} is stopped.", this.ToolName));
            }
        }
    }
```

I call this Stop() for 6 threads, previous 5 are stopped normally, but not the last one. Please, can somebody help? What should I do to eliminate this behavior?

UPD

```
     public void AddThread(Thread t, string name = "")
    {
        lock(_threadPool)
        {
            t.Name = name;
            _threadPool.Add(t, name);
        }
    }


    public void RemoveThread(Thread t)
    {
        lock(_threadPool)
        {
            _threadPool.Remove(t);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Need to know what that "ThreadPool" is in this case, and how it's Count changes. As is, seems not enough info to answer the question.

Comment: @Evk I use it like a ThreadPool - private readonly Dictionary<Thread, string> _threadPool = new Dictionary<Thread, string>();

Comment: But in the code above it is not shown how\when you add\remove items to that dictionary.

Comment: @Evk The post was updated.

Comment: Well that's still not enough unfortunately. When you do the while loop with Thread.Sleep, you expect something will remove a thread from that pool (so call RemoveThread). What code will do that? Maybe you can just post the whole class which contains that Stop method.

Comment: *bool* is not a synchronization primitive nor is it thread-safe.  This kind of code goes wrong when the x86 jitter optimizer decides to store the *bool* in a cpu register, setting it to *true* has no effect on the register value.  You did not post that code.   Once bitten, twice shy, use ManualResetEventSlim instead.